# Obtaining a v2 Google Maps API key

Tags: google-maps

It seems that in between the development of my website and the go-live (now) Google has phased out the Google Maps v2 API. I'm all for progress but to rewrite all my map code seems to be a bit too much for me to handle at this point in time.

Is it sill possible to obtain a Google Maps v2 API key in some hidden corner of the web?

Comment: It's possible to use the v2 API without any key at all.  Here's an [example](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://codethink.no-ip.org/mapHacks.html).

Comment: Indeed. You are right! Can you add that as an answer to I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get a new Console key from https://code.google.com/apis/console as described in the Version 3 docs at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key. Console keys work with Version 2 and provide the benefits of statistics reporting.

It's against the Terms to use the API without a key, and in fact this won't work on domains which aren't Google's like http://codethink.no-ip.org/mapHacks.html. The webcache version of that page works because it's on a Google domain.

Comment: So Google finally patched that exploit?  Good for them.  It certainly _used_ to work on non-Google domains.  And yes, against the terms-of-service, but if you don't have an API key then you haven't agreed to be bound by the terms-of-service so they're effectively null and void.

Comment: Can this console key be used for more than one project? If I want to create a new `Server key` I get the message that the old one will be replaced. Do I need an new Google account for each project?

Comment: @testing It looks like you can only have one server key per project (you need to give a list of applicable IP addresses). You can have lots of browser keys per project and match different urls to each browser key. You can have more than one project associated with a single Google account.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Currently, I'm using the same key for multiple domains. I saw that I can restrict the referer. I didn't looked for the difference between `Server key` and `Browser key` though. What is your recommended way?