# Google maps: how to generate a key for Google Maps v2?

Tags: google-maps

I have an old website that uses Google maps v2. Previously the website was running under http://domain1.edu. Now it is runs under http://domain2.edu. It appears that I need to update the map key.

On the internet, I was looking for how to do this. I find incomplete info at Google's own website. Here is the link for v2 map key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction?csw=1#Obtaining_Key

It says:

```
To create your API key, visit the APIs Console at https://code.google.com/apis/console and log in with your Google Account.

Click the Services link from the left-hand menu, then activate the Google Maps API v2 service.

Once the service has been activated, your API key is available from the API Access page, in the Simple API Access section. Maps API applications use the Key for browser apps
```

First, I am unable to find "Google Maps API v2" service mentioned above. I am able to find Google Maps API v3, and so I enabled it. I used the key mentioned at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

However, the website key is still not working.

Here is the page with Google map: http://nmai.si.edu/nafvf/attend.aspx

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtaining a v2 Google Maps API key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732950/obtaining-a-v2-google-maps-api-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the deprecated [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference), those keys are no longer available (as the documentation you point to indicates).  You need to use a v3 key, and make sure you have the referrers set correctly for that key (you really should update your map to use the v3 API...)

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v2_MW_example_map.html) (copied from [Mike Williams' v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/), just changed the key)

Comment: Should be.  I you having issues doing that?  It should work at least through 11/19. (and it [works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v2_MW_example_map.html))

Comment: Then you did something wrong, can't tell what without more information (like the javascript error and what your code looks like).  If it was a working v2 map, just changing the key to a new one _should_ have worked.  Did you change anything else?  Perhaps you might need to ask a different question...

Comment: thanks so much for following up with me. If you look at http://nmai.si.edu/nafvf/attend.aspx you can see the error (after waiting a few seconds). I did not change anything, just replaced the key as google document says.

Comment: How are the referers configured for that key?  Do you have the "Google Maps API v3" service enabled?

Comment: Yes. I did what you asked. Anyway, I quickly found a v3 example online and updated the map as you suggested. Now with the same v3 key, the error disappears. Thanks for following up with me so far! All the best.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key) says how to generate the key for android. You need to get the SHA1 of your signing key and then gotto google console to generate the key.